# use remainder to dived by and get result in swift

Tags: swift

I want to divide width by height to get the area. Then use that and divide by 350. If the remainder is more than 25 then add 1 to the result of the last equation. I'll preface this is that i am totally new to programming. here's what I have so far.

```
 var width = (Int) ()
 var height = (Int) ()
 var gal = (Int) ()
 var area = (Int)()
 width = 45
 height = 45
 area = height * width

 gal =  (area / 350)
 var galSurpluss = (area % 350)
 galSurpluss >=25, <=350 (if statement here?)
```

So that is where I breakdown if the number from galSurpluss is more than 25 I want it to be 1 and then add that to the result of gal.
I know there is a simple thing here that I am missing. Messing around in a playground and trying to make this work. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [Apple swift language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), there are lots of similar examples there.

```
let width = 45
let height = 45
let area = height * width

var gal = area / 350
let galSurpluss = area % 350
if galSurpluss >= 25 {
    gal++
}
println(gal)
// 6
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking through the reference and couldn't figure it out. I had the idea and was close to this after posting but not right. Thanks much.